# Jpanel not being refreshed after screen change

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, thread-sleep

I am creating a menu that links to my game when I click play.

```
 package GameScreen;

 import java.awt.Graphics; import java.awt.Rectangle; import
 java.awt.event.MouseEvent; import java.awt.event.MouseListener; import
 javax.swing.ImageIcon; import javax.swing.JComponent;

 public class MainMenu  extends JComponent
         implements MouseListener 
{ 
 private GameScreen PlayGame; private ImageIcon bg = new
 ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bg.jpg")); private ImageIcon
 ButtonPlay = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button.jpg"));
 private ImageIcon ButtonOptions = new
 ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button2.jpg")); private ImageIcon
 ButtonHS = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button3.jpg"));
 private ImageIcon ButtonQuit = new
 ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button4.jpg")); private Rectangle
 Boundsplay = new Rectangle (340, 250, 400, 100); private Rectangle
 BoundsOptions = new Rectangle (340, 350, 400, 100); private Rectangle
 BoundsHS = new Rectangle (340, 450, 400, 100); private Rectangle
 BoundsQuit = new Rectangle (340, 550, 400, 100);

     public MainMenu(GameScreen Play)
     {
         PlayGame = Play;
         setSize (1024,768);
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
         g.drawImage(bg.getImage(), 0, 0, 1024, 768, null);        
         g.drawImage(ButtonPlay.getImage(), 340, 250, 400, 100, null);
         g.drawImage(ButtonOptions.getImage(),340, 350, 400, 100, null);
         g.drawImage(ButtonHS.getImage(),340, 450, 400, 100, null);
         g.drawImage(ButtonQuit.getImage(),340, 550, 400, 100, null);
         addMouseListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     @Override
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
     if(Boundsplay.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))    {
                     PlayGame.PlayGame();
    }
     if(BoundsOptions.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))     {
               System.out.println("hit options");   }
     if(BoundsHS.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))  {
               System.out.println("hit HS");    }
     if(BoundsQuit.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))    {
               System.out.println("hit Quit");  }

     }

     @Override
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

     }

     @Override
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

     }

 }
```

As you can see hitting play will call this PlayGame.PlayGame(); and this will work however it will not refresh, so it will stay on the menu until I minimize and open or resize the panel to force it to refresh.
Any ideas how I can get it to refresh? Or something that is wrong and causing it not to refresh?

Below is the class in which the play game method is called from.

```
package GameScreen;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;





public class GameScreen 
extends JFrame
implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
private Thread animation = new Thread(this);
private AniScreen aniscreen = new AniScreen();;
private MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu(this);;
private HighScores highscores = new HighScores();


public GameScreen()
{
   super("Zombie defense!");
   setBounds(20,20,1024,768);
   setContentPane (mainmenu);
   //setContentPane (highscores);
   animation.start();
   addKeyListener(this);
   setVisible (true);
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
}

public void PlayGame()
{
    setContentPane (aniscreen);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       GameScreen gs = new GameScreen();
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      while (true)
      {
            aniscreen.repaint();
            mainmenu.repaint();
            highscores.repaint();

         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(30);
         }
         catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {

            }
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
   {
         }

   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
      if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
        aniscreen.moveplayer(0,20);
      }
       if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      {
        aniscreen.moveplayer(0,-20);

      }

   }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {
      aniscreen.moveplayer(0,0);
   }
}
```

As always thanks for any help or ideas put forward,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting

```
panel.repaint();
panel.revalidate();
```

after you've invoked the `PlayGame();` method?

Comment: aniscreen.revalidate(); got it working. Thanks for your help :)